# Will Monero host CryptoNote.org?

Tags: cryptonote

It seems cryptonote.org is offline.
Will Monero community bring it back?
While Monero is a variant of CryptoNote.

Answer (score 1):

- Monero is not some entity
- Welcome to the world of domain name ownership

I'm sure there are *many* people *involved with* Monero that would host a site at that domain name, getting control of the domain name is another matter entirely.